# Is it possible to call an Intent from just an SMS text

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to call Android intent from just a text?
I am planning to send a text to user as a SMS, on clicking the text it should call an Intent.

As I will not have control on the end user device,I dont want to write an App.
Its more like send a text and launch an already installed App on clicking it.

Comment: You want to call the intent through test or textview on which the text will appear. ??

Comment: Regarding your question the answer is simply no till now, but not impossible.

Comment: impossible .............

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you would be able to launch the Intent of another App from an SMS.  Especially if you have no control of the device, or more importantly the App you are wanting to launch with the Intent (ie, you can not launch another Private App using an Intent if you are not validated - there are ways to do allow this to happen, but the Private App developer would have to specifically enable this).

As an alternative, you could include the link to their Play Store App, which would launch the Play Store (where the user could then open the App).

Comment: Thanks all for the info  Shawn, Ravi @Booger

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Make your application handle the Broadcast of new SMS received and from that BroadCast Reciever class you can filter the text and open the particular intent.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the app you are launching is "watching" the URL. for example, google maps handles "http://map.google.com/"..., and yelp handles "http://www.yelp.com/...". If you send a text sms contains the URL and user clicks on it, it will launch the app (at least give you an option).

However if you want to launch an arbitrary app, no.